# How to force a window to maintain a certain width/height ratio when resized

Tags: c++, winapi

I want my window to always maintain a certain ratio of let's say 1.33333333. So, if the window is `width = 800, height = 600` and the user changes the width to 600, I want to change the height to 450 automatically.

I'm already intercepting `WM_SIZE` but I don't know if it's enough; also I don't know how to change the width or height to maintain my ratio.

Comment: Slightly different question, but generally the same answer as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406168/constraining-window-position-to-desktop-working-area

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[WM_SIZING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632647(VS.85).aspx) is sent to the window while the user is resizing the window.

Rather handle [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632653(VS.85).aspx) - this is sent by the internal SetWindowPos function when code (or the user) changes the window size and will ensure that even tile & cascade operations obey your sizing policy.

Answer (score 3):

See `WM_SIZING`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632647.aspx

Processing this message allows you to change resulting window size.

Answer (score -1):

Try the **[Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=VS.90).aspx)** event.  There is an example of how to maintain a desired aspect ration in the link.

Comment: I'm not using .NET, and that's .NET I believe :/